# Remove the selected elements from the image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I have [this](https://imgur.com/GWnJRlZ) image with tables where I want to remove the tabular structure from the image so that it can work more effectively with Tesseract. I used the following code to create a boundary around the table (and individual cells) so that it can be deleted.

```
img =cv2.imread('bfir.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
img1 = np.ones(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)*255
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)
(_,contours,h) = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(approx)==4:
        cv2.drawContours(img1,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),2)
```

This draws green lines around the table like [this](https://imgur.com/9iCX8Iu) image.

Next, I tried the `cv2.subtract` method to subtract the table from the image, somewhat like this.

```
final_img = cv2.subtract(img1, img)
```

But this didn't work as I expected and gives me a grayscale image with the table still in it. [Link](https://imgur.com/AmIy8gA)

While I just want the original image in B&W with the table removed. I am using OpenCV for the first time so I don't know what I am doing wrong and I am sorry for the long post but if anybody can please help with how to go about with this or just point me in the right direction about how to remove the table, that would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:
As suggested by [RobAu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461499/robau) it can also work with simply drawing the contours in white in the first place but I don't know how to do that without losing the rest of the data in the preprocessing stage.

Comment: I have a code for detecting rectangles and making them into their own picture if youre interested

Comment: That would be very helpful but I want to completely get rid of the table here instead of making it into a separate image. Please share it anyway, I can try and modify it to suit my needs :)

Comment: I will, post it as an answer, but you dont have to mark it answered, its mostly for the formatting. I'm not too familiar with open CV yet so this is unfortunately the best i can do

Comment: Why don't you just draw the contours in white on the original image?

Comment: I can definitely do that but I will admit that most of the work so far has been taken from here itself (like a true developer) and I am afraid I don't exactly understand how to draw the contours without removing the remaining data, as it is doing now ([example](https://imgur.com/9iCX8Iu)). (I am guessing it has something to do with thresholding which is 'blurring' the background data to draw the contours)

Comment: You are not overwriting the image. In your code the original image `img` stays the same. Instead you crate a new image `img1` on which you are drawing the green contours.

Comment: Yeah. I see that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and simply overwrite the cells that represent the borders. This can be done by creating a mask image, and then using that as reference as to where to overwrite pixels in the original.

This can be done with:

```
mask_image = np.zeros(img.shape[0:2], np.uint8)    
cv2.drawContours(mask_image, contours, -1, color=255, thickness=2)
border_points = np.array(np.where(mask_image == 255)).transpose()
background = [0, 0, 0] # Change this to the colour you want
for point in border_points :
    img[point[0], point[1]] = background
```

---

**Update:**

You could use the 3-channel you already created for the mask, but that slightly complicates the algorithms. The mask image propose is more fitted for the task, but I will try to adapt it to your code:

```
# Create your mask image as usual...
border_points = np.array(np.where(img1[:,:,1] == 255)).transpose() # Only look at channel 2
background = [0, 0, 0] # Change this to the colour you want
for point in border_points :
    img[point[0], point[1]] = background
```

---

**Update** to do as @RobAu suggested (quicker than my previous methods):

```
line_thickness = 3  # Change this value until it looks the best.
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, color=(0,0,0), thickness=line_thickness )
```

---

*Please note I didn't test this code. So it might need some further fiddling.*

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. Can't I use the second image (img1, with the green borders) itself as the mask?

Comment: You could, but then you will have to slightly adapt the algorithm I provided. I essentially do the same as you, except I create an single channel image. I'll try to update my answer for you to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the update and explanation. I only asked because the first solution kept giving me the error 'IndexError: index 5549 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5092' even after I tried changing around the values. The second solution at least seems to be working but I must be doing something stupid still as I am still getting either the original image itself or the img1 as the output.

Comment: For the first error it seems that the `x` and `y` axis are getting mixed up. Try adding `.transpose()` after `np.array(np.where(mask_image == 255))`. If that doesn't work, check the `shape` property of the image matrices after each step to make sure they are all the same. For your second problem, are you sure the `for loop` is running?

Comment: `.transpose()` method worked! But it gives output like [this](https://imgur.com/UqWUDuo). As for the second solution, I debugged my program and it did go into the loop.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! But @RobAu's suggestion is quicker. I updated my answer to show how to do that. You were basically doing the same thing already, you just needed to change the colour.

Comment: While your solution works, trying out @RobAu answer with inside the `for` loop in the original code in my question works better as it gives much clearer output, yet still leaves lots of lines ([example](https://imgur.com/wuK0mvv)). I tried changing the various values but it doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: That means we are on the right track. What happens when you rather use the colour green again, and plot it on the *original* image? `Color=(0,255,0)` instead of `Color=(0,0,0)`. Do this so we can see exactly where you are drawing the lines on the image, and if you are drawing it on the correct place.

Comment: When I use the green colour, it seems to be drawing correctly just on the borders ([link](https://imgur.com/lxExrND)) although if I play around with the threshold, it starts to overlap with the text as well. But this same config utterly fails when I change it back to white (255, 255, 255) (I am guessing here that although its not visible to the eye (at least on my laptop), some overlap might be still happening in this case too).

Comment: Seems like the lines you are drawing isn't solid enough. Try adding the parameter `lineType=cv2.LINE_8` to `cv2.drawContours` function`.

Comment: That didn't work but following your lead, I changed the last parameter here `cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],-1,(255,255,255),5)` to 5 and it worked almost perfectly! Thanks for all your help and patience and keeping up with the stupid. :D

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! It's no problem at all. Just please remember to `Accept` the answer if you believe it helped, and `upvote` if you feel it deserves it. I will try to update my answer with the necessary details. :)

Comment: I can't upvote as I don't have enough rep but I have accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> As a reference to the comments of this question, this is an example of a code that locates rectangles and creates new images for each one, this was an attempt at creating individual images of a picture of shredded paper. Some of the values will need to be changed for it to locate the rectangles with the right amount of size
>
> There is also some code for tracking sizes of images and the code is made up by 50% what i have written and 50% by stackoverflow help.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

fileName = ['9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1','0']

img = cv2.imread('#YOUR IMAGE#')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(gray,kernel,iterations = 2)
kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = 2)

edged = cv2.Canny(dilation, 30, 200)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

rects = [cv2.boundingRect(cnt) for cnt in contours]
rects = sorted(rects,key=lambda  x:x[1],reverse=True)


i = -1
j = 1
y_old = 5000
x_old = 5000
for rect in rects:
    x,y,w,h = rect
    area = w * h
    print('width: %d and height: %d' %(w,h))
    if   w > 50 and h > 500:
        print('abs:')
        print(abs(x_old - x))
        if abs(x_old - x) > 0:
            print('writing')
            x_old = x
            x,y,w,h = rect

            out = img[y+10:y+h-10,x+10:x+w-10]
            cv2.imwrite('assets/newImage' + fileName[i] + '.jpg', out)

            j+=1
        if (y_old - y) > 1000:
            i += 1
            y_old = y
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but I don't think this is going to be of much help. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Even though, the given input image links are not working & so I obviously doesn't know the following is what you have asked for, I learnt something from your question, when I was working on, removing table structure lines from given image, I like to share what I have learnt, for the future readers.

I followed the steps provided in [opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html) to remove the lines. 
But that only removed the horizontal lines. When I tried to remove vertical lines, the result image only had the vertical lines. The text in the table was not there.

Then I came across your question & saw `final_img = cv2.subtract(img1, img)` in the question. Tried that & it worked great.

Here are the steps that I followed:

```
# Load the image
src = cv.imread(argv[0], cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
# Check if image is loaded fine
if src is None:
    print ('Error opening image: ' + argv[0])
    return -1
# Show source image
cv.imshow("src", src)
# [load_image]
# [gray]
# Transform source image to gray if it is not already
if len(src.shape) != 2:
    gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else:
    gray = src
# Show gray image
# show_wait_destroy("gray", gray)
# [gray]
# [bin]
# Apply adaptiveThreshold at the bitwise_not of gray, notice the ~ symbol
gray = cv.bitwise_not(gray)
bw = cv.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, \
                            cv.THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2)
# Show binary image
# show_wait_destroy("binary", bw)
# [bin]
# [init]
# Create the images that will use to extract the horizontal and vertical lines
horizontal = np.copy(bw)
vertical = np.copy(bw)

# [horiz]
# [vert]
# Specify size on vertical axis
rows = vertical.shape[0]
verticalsize = rows / 10
# Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology operations
verticalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))
# Apply morphology operations
vertical = cv.erode(vertical, verticalStructure)
vertical = cv.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure)

# [init]
# [horiz]
# Specify size on horizontal axis
cols = horizontal.shape[1]
horizontal_size = cols / 30
# Create structure element for extracting horizontal lines through morphology operations
horizontalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))
# Apply morphology operations
horizontal = cv.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
horizontal = cv.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
lines_removed = cv.subtract(gray, vertical + horizontal)

show_wait_destroy("lines_removed", ~lines_removed)
```

#### Input:

[image: Input image]

#### Output:

[image: Output image]

**Few things that I changed from the sources:**

1. `verticalsize = rows / 10`, here, I do not understand the significance of the number `10`. In the documentation, 30 was used. I got better result with 10. I guess, the less the division number, the large the structure element & here, as we are targeting straight lines, reducing the number works.
2. In the documentation, vertical lines are processed after horizontal lines. I reversed the order
3. I swapped the parameters to `cv2.substract()`. I used `cv2.subtract(img, img1)`.